# How to import Github wysiwyg Editor into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, wysiwyg

I want to make my  in html file as a markdown editor. Just like this stackoverflow. After some research i found this [bootstrap-markdown](https://github.com/toopay/bootstrap-markdown). I liked this and wanted to use it.

According to the description in [demo](http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/) i could use it simply by using `data-provide="markdown" attribute`

```html
<form>
    <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title?" />
    <textarea name="content" data-provide="markdown" rows="10"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me to understand **how to import this github project into my plain html file.
So that i can just give `<textarea name="content" data-provide="markdown"></textarea>` and it displays the markdown editor.**

Comment: At the top of the [site](http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/) are two download icons (the folders). Click either one and add the CSS and JS file in there to your document.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you didn't download the files from the demo.

First you should download their sources (by clicking on the tar.gz or .zip at the bottom of the navbar)

Then you should add the `bootstrap-markdown.js` and `bootstrap-markdown.css` in the same folder as your html file (ideally in some subfolder) and finally add them as css or javascript files, eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap-markdown.css">
```

and

```
<script src="./js/bootstrap-markdown.js"></script>
```

You should also have bootstrap and jquery loaded in your project